# Print mode for do notation in isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to figure out the correct setting for the print mode in Isabelle/Jedit to have do notations displayed in my output instead of binds. I tried "do_notation", "do_notations" and "donotation" so far.

Is there maybe a documentation for all the possible settings?

Comment: I think it is just `do`.